# Prevent vim from being launched in vim

Tags: terminal-buffer

When I'm using the terminal feature on nvim sometimes I run the last command again out of habit (thinking that I'll re-run the unittests for what I'm coding at the moment or something), but the latest command in my shell's history is something like `nvim path/to/my/project-folder`

Naturally, what happens is It opens nvim inside of the nvim terminal. I've found it's fairly easy to exit from the inner nvim, but I was wondering if there's a better approach here.

Would it be advisable to just make vim exit when this happens? How would I do that?

Comment: Are you talking about using `!!` to run the last command? If so, get in the habit of using `<Esc>k` instead and you'll know what you're about to execute before you execute it. :)  (This assumes you're using `set -o vi`.)

Comment: Nah, I'm pressing the up arrow key in fish then hitting enter. I for sure see the command, but muscle memory is sometimes too fast for me to not hit enter first.

Comment: Can't help you with that problem. Try self-discipline. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This little snippet of code works for me if I put it in my vimrc:

```
if exists('$VIMRUNNING') && ! has('gui_running')
    qall!
else
    let $VIMRUNNING = 1
endif
```

I included the check for `gui_running` so you can start gVim from inside a terminal, but not a console vim.

Comment: This works great. I tried adding `echo "dummy! read before running!"` before `qall!` but that was really just a shot in the dark... Would it be possible to echo to the term like what I imagined?

Comment: LOL. Don't be so hard on yourself.

Comment: oh actually a `sleep` between echo and qall works great.

Comment: I've devised this ingenious `/bin/sh` script to do something simmilar for another purpose... I wonder if this could be repurposed as a different answer to this question? `[ $(ps -jh | grep vim | wc -l) -gt 1 ]`

Comment: More concise and faster, if you're using Bash or zsh: [[ $(ps -C vim -o pid h) ]]